# Access 2010 connection string from VB.net without using the Access 2007 database engine

Tags: vb.net, connection-string, ms-access-2010

I have a VB.net program using an Access 2010 database.  Thus far, I have been using the Access 2007 database engine and connection string as:

ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=MyDB.accdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=MyPassword"

This works fine but it requires the 32 bit Access 2007 database engine, which will not allow some 64 bit installations to be installed.  Therefore, I am looking for the connection string that will work with Access 2010 and not require the Access 2007 DB runtime.

I have searched the web and this forum, and they all say to install the Access 2007 DB engine, which is exactly what I want to get away from.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks much!

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: You can't.

There is no (practical) way to access an .accdb database without using the Access Database Engine.